# Null display when parsing json from php to android

Tags: java, php, android, json

here is my php code

```
$titikPetaInti = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($hasil2))
{
     $titikPetaInti[] = $row['koordinat'];
}

$data = "{titikPeta:".json_encode($titikPetaInti)."}";
echo $data;
?>
```

then here is my android code
xResultTitikPeta is result request to php

```
jObject = new JSONObject(xResultTitikPeta);
        JSONArray myArray1 = (JSONArray) jObject.getJSONArray("titikPeta");
        String[]titikPeta = new String[myArray1.length()];

        for(int a = 0; a < myArray1.length(); a++)
        {
            titikPeta[a] = myArray1.getJSONObject(a).toString();
        }
        teks1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        teks1.setText(Arrays.toString(titikPeta));
```

it displaying null at emulator like no value

**--EDIT--**

i think there something mistake in parsing code, cus when i display the xResultTitikPeta in android, it give me string result

here is result of xResultTitikPeta

```
{titikPeta:["-8.705378,115.225189","-8.56056700000000,115.42395100000","-8.57659700000000,115.40065300000","-8.55596300000000,115.41085700000","-8.51855200000000,115.491908000000","-8.54743200000000,115.41036800000","-8.56551100000000,115.45173900000","-8.44321000000000,115.616019000000"]}
```

Comment: are you sure if $row['koordinat'] is settign a value?

Comment: @Sana, yes. and i have tried the php code directly and it give me the result, but when it parse to android, they return null value

Comment: Can you show us the `xResultTitikPeta` string? Have you run it through a site like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to check the syntax?

Comment: @Ken, yes the result is string

Comment: one can test the code [here](http://ideone.com) but with some includes also.. Also this question needs some java guys, but question has not that tag.

Comment: @sephtian Thanks for the string, but as others have said, you need quotes around `titikPeta`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found your bug! As well as fixing the `$data = json_encode(array("titikPeta" => $titikPetaInti));` issue, the problem is here:

```
titikPeta[a] = myArray1.getJSONObject(a).toString();
```

The elements of `myArray1` are actually of type `string` and cause an exception to be thrown, so you need instead:

```
titikPeta[a] = myArray1.getString(a);
```

This produces the output of:

```
[-8.705378,115.225189, -8.56056700000000,115.42395100000, -8.57659700000000,115.40065300000, -8.55596300000000,115.41085700000, -8.51855200000000,115.491908000000, -8.54743200000000,115.41036800000, -8.56551100000000,115.45173900000, -8.44321000000000,115.616019000000]
```

As each element in your array is of the form `"-8.705378,115.225189"`, the JSON parser assumes they are strings. If you change the elements to `"-8.705378","115.225189"` you can also use:

```
titikPeta[a] = Double.toString(myArray1.getDouble(a));
```

However, the first version will work too.

Note: my personal preference is that I would declare each array element as:

```
{"x":-8.705378,"y":115.225189}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is **malformed** JSON! no double quotes on key.

```
$data = "{titikPeta:".json_encode($titikPetaInti)."}";
```

instead do:

```
$data = '{"titikPeta":'.json_encode($titikPetaInti).'}';
```

**EDITED:**

Ok, remove that hand made approach:

```
$data = json_encode(array("titikPeta"=>$titikPetaInti));
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$data = "{\"titikPeta\":".json_encode($titikPetaInti)."}";
```